# Time to interactive and pagespeed score sometimes fails with lighthouse npm

Tags: npm, puppeteer, pagespeed, lighthouse, pagespeed-insights

I'm using lighthouse npm to test some random URLs... Sometime it fails with leaving

```
['audits']['interactive']['rawValue']
```

and

```
['categories']['performance']['score']
```

empty.

Is there something in the config to avoid this or is "retry until it does not fail anymore" my best change.

That's my setup. It's puppeteer + lighthouse

```
    Start Puppeteer + open URL
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ args: ['--no-sandbox'] });
    const page = await browser.newPage()
    await page.goto(urlToTest, {
        waitUntil: 'networkidle2',
        timeout: 0
    });

    //Start Lighthouse 
    let opts = {
        chromeFlags: ['--show-paint-rects'],
        output: 'html',
        throttlingMethod: 'provided',
        throttling: {   
            throughputKbps: 8000,
            downloadThroughputKbps: 8000,
            uploadThroughputKbps: 2000
        }
    };

    opts.port = (new URL(browser.wsEndpoint())).port;
    let lighthouseResults = await lighthouse(urlToTest, opts, config = null);
```